# Jquery grids compatible issue with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, compatibility

I am using http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/07/draggable-image-boxes-grid/ .

Everything works well. But the drag function at the home page doesnt work in firefox. I am a rookie in jquery and i dont know how to resolve it. kindly help on it. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any error in console ???

Comment: How do i check that?

Comment: @user3230795, go to Menu > Developer > Web console, in Firefox.

Comment: Yes there is one Js error and few css errors.

here is the Js error which am not able to understand

Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Found something interesting this morning.. The plugin works fine in firefox in other systems except the one am using.. all systems are running the same version of firefox 31.0. Is the browser in my system disabling the plugin or something? how do i check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys i just found out that the plugin works in all other systems except my system..the problem is solved now.. thanks a lot.